# are attributes top, left, right, bottom legal in the same declaration as position:relative?

Tags: css

I understand that you can declare `position:relative` in a div element.  Then, if you declare `position:absolute` in a child block element, you can then use top, left, bottom and right to position that element "relative" to the parent element which was declared as `position:relative`

In the CSS code I inherited I'm seeing a combination of `position:relative` and say top or left in the same declaration.  Is this a mistake? And if so why would it be used?

Comment: There is no mistake....Check- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @Pilot, I am not trying to be rude but in my subject line and the body I have 3 question marks. Ironically, your question doesn't have one.  I just thought that was sort of bizarre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css `top, left, right, bottom` are applicable to all the positioned elements (i.e other than `position:static`).

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b32fd6m7/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN article on `top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top):

> For relatively positioned elements (those with position: relative), it specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

Basically the top/right/bottom/left properties move a relatively-positioned element a given distance from where it would be normally placed.

Comment: yes, and a relatively positioned element is NOT taken out of the flow but an absolutely positioned element IS.  That I did not know (but do now).  I have always just used position:relative as an anchor point (no left or top etc.), so that I can use that div as an anchor point for a position:absolute element inside.